# Unable to PUT resource xml file via Postman

Tags: docusignapi

In the [DocuSign Postman Collection](https://github.com/docusign/postman-collections), I am unable to use the method to update a resource XML file:

```
{{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/brands/{{brandId}}/resources/{{resourceContentType}}
```

When initially trying to use the endpoint, I get the following error:

```
{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER","message":"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. A filename was not found in the Content-Disposition header ('filename=\"filename.ext\""}
```

The docs do mention the need to include a Content-Disposition header, though upon adding:
`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="DocuSign_SigningResource.xml"`, I get the error:

```
{"errorCode":"BRAND_RESOURCES_XML_LOAD_OR_PARSE_ERROR","message":"XML syntax error. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}
```

I have confirmed my XML is valid. I get this same error if I try to include a file that does not exist, so I am not confident the contents of the XML file have anything to do with the error I am receiving.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Update: I was able to get this working by updating the request body format. The DocuSign Postman Collection indicates form-data with a file reference is expected. It was only when I updated the request body to be raw xml and pasting the xml file contents directly into the request body that I was able to make a successful request.